# Erro ao compilar projeto com QT

Tags: c++, qt

Olá,
sou iniciante no qt, fiz um curso de C++ com QT em 2013 mas não pude levar a diante o aprendizado e agora estou retomando.
Agora estou tentando compilar um projeto simples, apenas crio um novo projeto em qt widget, ele cria automaticamente uma tela main e eu não mexi em nada, só tentei rodar este programa criado pela própria IDE e ocorre o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alertas gerados pelo compilador (contidos na imagem):

> Warning: overriding recipe for target 'debug/main.o'
>
> Warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'debug/main.o'

Comment: Copie o erro do log e cole aqui. Também coloque o código se não é impossivel descobrir em que arquivo esta a falha. Até mais.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edson, esta imagem que você linkou mostra 2 advertências, avisando que você está sobrepondo targets de compilação.

Neste caso específicamente você definiu o nome da janela principal do seu projeto como "main", o qual é o nome exatamente do arquivo gerado pelo Qt Creator para inicializar o programa em C++ (main.cpp), portanto você impede que o projeto seja iniciado no padrão do Qt.

Recomendo que você altere o nome da janela principal para qualquer coisa diferente de "main", como por exemplo MainWindow (sugestão padrão do Qt Creator).

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Era isto mesmo Bruno Bermann, mudei o nome da form e funcionou. É a força do hábito, em outras linguagens sempre usei main para a tela principal, valeu pela dica.

Comment: Quanto ao formato da pergunta, vou tentar melhorar daqui em diante, tenham um pouco de paciência aí pessoal, sou iniciante tanto no fórum quanto em QT, e vamos em frente.